# Mistaken word in pop-up when trying to create plural of a tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I know that we usually get an error up when we try to create a plural of an already existing tag, but today I noticed that the error pop had a wrong word. This was on [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) when trying to create a [shrimps](/questions/tagged/shrimps) tag. I got:

[image]

The error message should be

> You are attempting to create the tag [shrimps]; however the tag **[shrimp]** already exists [...].

I have been able to reproduce this on

Meta

[image]

and Stack Overflow

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the upcoming build rev `2013.11.18.1655` on meta and `2013.11.18.1160` on sites.